# What's the Ubuntu equivalent of Active Directory?

Tags: networking, active-directory

I have around a 40+ user network running Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop and Ubuntu Server.
What is the best tool to use to run authentication on users? Webmin? 
Similar to what AD does for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to create an [OpenLDAP server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html) for clients to authenticate against. Webmin is just a frontend (or rather, it has a plugin that is a frontend) to LDAP. 
I didn't really find a good GUI frontend for OpenLDAP (if that is what you are looking for).

Comment: Active Directory is not just LDAP!

Comment: Thank you. Was looking at that a while ago. But thought if there was a nice gui for the client to be able to use :(

Comment: @JorgeCastro That is true, but since he didn't mention he needed any support for Windows machines (and I don't know of anything else similar to Active Directory), I didn't think Samba4 was the right move.